# android-mips: ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘nlink_t’

Tags: android, mips

In compiling a library for android for mips, I am running into

```
In file included from /Volumes/Projects/api9-mips/sysroot/usr/include/strings.h:42,
                 from /Volumes/Projects/api9-mips/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:42,
                 from runtime/api.c:2:
/Volumes/Projects/api9-mips/sysroot/usr/include/sys/types.h:64: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘nlink_t’
```

sys/types.h itself has

```
typedef __kernel_key_t       key_t;
typedef __kernel_mode_t      mode_t;
typedef __kernel_nlink_t     nlink_t; <-------- 64
#ifndef _OFF_T_DEFINED_
#define _OFF_T_DEFINED_
```

The only kind of strange thing in that section is that __kernel_nlink_t is separated from nlink_t by a space and a tab, where as all the rest of the _t typedefs are separated by spaces to their counter-part. How do I fix this?

Comment: Me too - close enough; ever find a solution?